# Call Flask API with Parameters from a different Python service (non-Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I built a very basic rest API and I would like to call my API from another Python service.

This is what I have in `flask_app.py`:

```
@app.route("/<kyw1>/<kyw2>/<start>/<end>/<country>")
def get_trends(kyw1, kyw2, start, end, country):
    kyws = [kyw1, kyw2]
    timeframe = start + " " + end
    pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-GB', tz=360)
    for x in range(0, len(kyws)):
        #currentKeyword = [kyws[x]]
        pytrend.build_payload(
            kw_list=kyws,
            cat=0,
            timeframe=timeframe,
            geo=country)
        data = pytrend.interest_over_time()
    csv_file_name = kyw1 + "_" + kyw2 + "_from_" + start + "_to_" + end + ".csv"
    export_trends(data, csv_file_name)
    return render_template("done.html")
```

So I am able to make a request to that service directly form my browser using the URL such as `my_domain.com/sun/sea/12032020/14032020/UK`

Now I am creating another Python service which is going to call that Flask API. My issue here is that from what I have seen online, the url should be constructed like this: `my_domain.com/sun&sea&12032020&14032020&UK` How can I fix this?

Comment: That is different, one is a route with different levels, the other is URL params. Can't the new python service call `my_domain.com/sun/sea/12032020/14032020/UK`  ?

Comment: It can actually, can I call a route with JSON data?

Comment: to send data you may use a POST request, not a GET

Comment: Yes you are right, I need to do a POST request. I don't really know how to send my parameters as people told me it's better to work with json

Comment: Are your parameter just the 5 elements of the route ?

Comment: Yes only those 5 parameters

Comment: You can continue to send them as a route, I don't understand what your problem is

Comment: When an API changes, as they often do, query strings are often more flexible and can be changed more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a choice between a couple of ways to get your data to your API. One is a variable URL. This means that it isn't a static, fixed-name URL but one with dynamic components, which is what you have already. Another way to do this is with URL arguments in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). This is universally more accepted, especially when it comes to APIs, because it gives developers more flexibility, as they can leave args out for defaults, etc. Also, with a URL, the order in which the variables come matters, **significantly**, whereas with the query string each one is named. It is very easy to change from variable URLs to query string args, and flask has a module called `request` for that. If this is your variable URL:

```py
@app.route('/api/<str:username>/<str:keyword>/str:field>')
def api(username,keyword,field):
    #do something with your data
    return jsonify(data=data)
```

Now what if you want to add more features to your api. Like a `size` parameter which the developer can change to receive more data?

Well, instead of having this long base URL, you can just have a simple `/api` route, to which developers can add URL arguments. Here's one way of doing that:

```py
@app.route('/api')
def api():
    username = request.args.get("username")
    if not username: # a tad of authorisation
        return jsonify(message="please submit a username in the query string")
    size = request.args.get("size")
    keyword = request.args.get("keyword")
    # etc etc
    return jsonify(results = results,message="success")
```

Now, over time, if you want to add more features, you don't need to change your API's URL, which will confuse developers. Instead, just utilise another request arg, like `type` or `id`.

You can see the difference between these two URLs, where the first is unclear what part of the URL refers to what bit:
`localhost:5000/api/trilby/socks/t-rex`

`localhost:500/api?username=trilby&keyword=socks&field=t-rex`

If you discontinue a URL arg, as in it no longer works, when developers include it in the query string it won't cause a 404 or break. Instead, the extra unwanted args will be ignored. That's why query string arguments are so favoured over full URLs in API programming.

Comment: Thank you monsieuralfonse64! You are more helpful than most of the ressources online! I know what I need to do now and how to use it

Comment: Quite welcome. If you ever use web/REST APIs they normally follow this pattern. If you found it helpful, there is in fact an upvote button for helpful and useful answers... ;)

Comment: I tried but " Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @Pierre56 see above, forgot to @

Comment: A google trends script that is going to store the csv inside a GCP bucket, this is at my internship

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Student in the UK